# does handbrake support conversion without re encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

specifically I want the equivalent of this command

```
for f in *.VOB;do ffmpeg -fflags +genpts  -i "$f" -c copy "${f%VOB}mp4";done
```

the output of the above won't play on quicktime

Answer (score 2):

Even if handbreak supported remuxing (changing the container without transcoding) it still would not play in QuickTime, because QuickTime does not support mpeg2 (the codec used in VOB)